# C++ persistence of objects declared within a block, memory leakage possibility?

Tags: c++, class, object, block, instantiation

First of all let me prefix this question with the following points:
1) I have searched Stackexchange for this issue, most of the code presented was difficult enough for me to follow in order to warrant Asking a new Question/Opening a new Thread about this. The closest i could find was this [Creating multiple class objects with the same name? c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975004/creating-multiple-class-objects-with-the-same-name-c) and unfortunately this is way past my scope of understanding

2) http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ has not really discussed this or i have missed it.

Now that this is out of the way:

Rectangle Class code:

```
class Rectangle {
private:
    int lineNumber;
    float valueMax;
    float valueMin;
public:
    Rectangle(SCStudyInterfaceRef sc, int lineNumber, float valueMax, float valueMin);
    int getLineNumber(); // member function of class
    float getValueMax(); // member function of class Rectangle
    float getValueMin(); // member function of class Rectangle
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(SCStudyInterfaceRef sc, int lineNumber0, float value1, float value2) {
    lineNumber = lineNumber0;
    int value2_greater_than_value1 = sc.FormattedEvaluate(value2, sc.BaseGraphValueFormat, GREATER_OPERATOR, value1, sc.BaseGraphValueFormat); 
    if (value2_greater_than_value1 == 1) {
        valueMax = value2;
        valueMin = value1;
    } else {
        valueMax = value1;
        valueMin = value2;
    }
}

int Rectangle::getLineNumber() {
    return lineNumber;
}

float Rectangle::getValueMax() {
    return valueMax;
}

float Rectangle::getValueMin() {
    return valueMin;
}
```

And here is the more important part, this code is running pretty much in a loop and will repeat everytime a certain event triggers it:

```
bool xxx = Conditions here

if (xxx) { 
// Draw new rectangle using plattforms code
code here

// Save rectangle information in the list:
Rectangle rect(sc, linenumbr + indexvalue, high, low);
(*p_LowRectanglesList).push_back(rect);
} 

bool yyy = conditions here

if (Short) { 
// Draw new rectangle using plattforms code
code here

// Save rectangle information in the list:
Rectangle rect(sc, linenumber + indexvalue, high, low);
(*p_HighRectanglesList).push_back(rect);
```

}

**So the question is the following:**

Since this is looped everytime an event triggers the second part of the code is going to be run, the bool condition is going to be checked, if its true its going to use plattform integrated code to draw a rectangle. Once it has drawn it this information is going to be passed to a new rectangle object/instance based on the Rectangle Class in the first part of the code using the: `Rectangle rect(sc, linenumber + indexvalue, high, low);` part and then save that information in a list which is in a different part of the code for now and irrelevant.

What exactly happens when there is a new Bool = True condition and the code gets executed after it has already been executed? Will the old rectangle object be simply replaced with a new rectangle object with the same name and using the new parameters (since they change on every instance due to the way the code is written)? Or are there now two objects of the Rectangle Class using the same name "rect" ?

It's technically speaking not even that important to me since the information of the parameters should be pushed into a list anyways using the `(*p_HighRectanglesList).push_back(rect);` part of the code

**So TL;DR:**
Does "rect" get destroyed/overwritten or are there now potentially limitless amounts of Rectangle Objects/Instances called "rect" floating around?

My Apologies for the wall of text but being a complete noob i thought it would be best to outline my thought process so that it will be easier for you to correct me on where I'm wrong.

Kind regards,
Orbital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `rect` is destroyed and recreated every loop. In C++, the scope of any variable declared in a block (in this case an `if()` statement) is limited to that block. Every time your program iterates, you get a new `rect`, and the old `rect` is gone.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and concise answer; and again my apologies for the "wall of text".

Answer (score 0):

To add, whenever you call NEW, you are basically allocating memory and creating Rectangle objects. NEW will allocate address to each instance. The pointer *rect will be pointing to the current memory address, and when you call rect with NEW again, now rect will be pointing to the new memory address the previous address becomes a NULL reference. However in C++ you have to worry about memory leaks unlike Java where you have a garbage collector.